# Timer to check activity on socket connection?

Tags: java, timer

We have a socket application which the snippet of the while loop is as below. What we would like to check is that say if it pass 30 seconds and no more data then shut the socket connection. At event if the some data is in then we reset the timer. Must I use the timer or system milliseconds

```
while ((readChar=readSocket.read()) != -1) 
{

  //processing.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the socket so that a read operation times out if no data is received within the specified interval.

From [the Socket Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29):

```
public void setSoTimeout(int timeout) throws SocketException
```

> Enable/disable SO_TIMEOUT with the specified timeout, in milliseconds. With this option set to a non-zero timeout, a read() call on the InputStream associated with this Socket will block for only this amount of time. If the timeout expires, a java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised, though the Socket is still valid. The option must be enabled prior to entering the blocking operation to have effect. The timeout must be > 0. A timeout of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout.
>
> ```
> Parameters:
>     timeout - the specified timeout, in milliseconds. 
> Throws:
>     SocketException - if there is an error in the underlying protocol, such as a TCP error.
> Since:
>     JDK 1.1
> See Also:
>     getSoTimeout()
> ```

Using this approach, you can read data, consume it (however your need to), and then read from the socket again.  If you get the timeout exception, then close the socket.

```
socket.setSoTimeout(30 * 1000);                  // timeout after 30 seconds

try
{
  while ((readChar=readSocket.read()) != -1)     // block reading data ...
  {
    // processing ...
  }
}
catch (SocketTimeoutException e)                 // we didn't get any data within 30 seconds ...
{
  socket.close();                                // ... close the socket
}
```

Comment: the problem now with socket.setSoTimeout is that for e.g if I set 30 seconds immediately after 30 seconds that the socket closes. What I required is that as long data keeping coming in just receive it. The moment after the last data in this batch then I would like to set a timer and check if in this 30 seconds no more data then only disconnect the socket?

Comment: SO_TIMEOUT will cause the SocketTimeoutException to be raised if 30 seconds elapse and no data has been received - (a) if data *is* being received, the timeout won't expire, and (b) it's up to you to take action and close the socket.  Now to clarify, are you saying that at the start you want to block indefinitely waiting for data to arrive -- then, once data has arrived, wait 30 seconds (in case more data arrives), and then close the socket? If so, then this can be achieved by just adding a few more checks to the code above to determine if we're in the 'initial' or 'post-data-received' state.

Comment: ok initially I will make the connection and keep reading character by character with the delimiter ask #. So once I see hash means I have read one full data/line. Thereafter I need to wait in 30 seconds no more data coming then only close the connection. Hope I am clear now. So even in the start I do not want to block indefinitely if no data comes in 30 seconds off the connection.

Comment: So, you accept the connection, then read from the input stream ...  Unless there is a >30s delay between reading two 'fragments' of a single 'line', then the above code should work.  Setting SO_TIMEOUT means that you read call will block for at most 30 seconds.  When you get sent data, doesn't the client send you a 'line' in one go?

Comment: The problem is that the client sends data in various length we tried before and another thing the line does not get terminated with a "\n". So for the time out how should I set so_timeout?

Comment: It doesn't matter how the data is represented (\n terminated or not).  SO_TIMEOUT will allow your *blocked* read() call to *unblock* if 30s (or whatever) elapses without the client sending any data. Say the client is sending a message that is going to be 32 bytes long.  What do you want to do if the client sends 16 bytes, and then doesn't send anything else for 2 minutes?

Comment: As long after 30seconds it is still idle and no single data is being sent then close the connection I do not look into the size at all. As long it is still sending then do not close.

Comment: I will try to implement and test it and get back to you soon on that ok.

Comment: yes it works perfectly I purposely tried like at 25th seconds send another data and the timeout reset back to another 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Use asynchronous NIO operations.
If you use java6, async operations are tricky, but there are many network libraries (Mina, Netty) though they are rather heavy.
If you use java7, true async network operations are implemented and are easy to use (nio2). Even more easier is to use a lightweight nio2 library from https://github.com/rfqu/df4j.